# Why does “ Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?” occur in a compiled template?

Tags: theming, media

After upgrading from 9.4.8 to 9.5.3 a problem came up (see below) so when I add more than one image in articles media field node-image, I get a 500 error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in /home/www/sites1/mysite.gr/astrosnews/web/sites/default/files/php/twig/63dee130963f5_field--field-node-image.h_OFwaH9BedIr0dxUMjz2WTf6If/M-GDNVdt5tDdsesr-7jYR7Xyr_xWOPal71qHp-7K3yk.php on line 89
```

The line 89 mentioned above is the below but is not produced by theme code.

```
if (((($__internal_compile_2 = ($context["items"] ?? null)) && is_array($__internal_compile_2) || $__internal_compile_2 instanceof ArrayAccess ? ($__internal_compile_2[0] ?? null) : null) != $context["item"])) {
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

**Update**

code which might be the source of the problem although it is not changed

```
  {% if items|length > 1 and view_mode == "full" %}
    <div class="image-listing-items clearfix">
      {% for item in items %}
        {% if items[0] != item %}
          <div class="image-listing-item">
            <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field__item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: This is theme code, the Twig engine compiles Twig to PHP. You can force recompiling by clearing the Twig PHP cache `drush ev "\Drupal::service('twig')->invalidate();"`. If this doesn't help then check the template `field--field-node-image` for anything unusual.

Comment: Clearing caches didn't help and there were no changes in theme and template field--field-node-image.twig
The code added in the original post seems to be the source althought nothing changed for years.

Answer (score 3):

This code line is expensive to calculate and could even cause a fatal error when the arrays/objects are very large:

```
{% if items[0] != item %}
```

Instead, use the [Twig loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable):

```
{% if not loop.first %}
```

Comment: Thank you @4uk4! The change you proposed in code worked! I am using a paid theme that is not updated anymore. Even if the items where only 2  or 3, when saving article I got http 500.

Comment: item(s) contains render arrays for the field content. Such render arrays change often by updating or installing and configuring additional modules. You've reached a point where the level of nesting simply was too much or somehow the render array built a recursive loop, which only causes problems when trying to traverse the array and the objects included to compare it,